# Does this hadith about patience exclude confiding in your spouse about hardships?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I received a [hadith as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZf1M.jpg) and tracked down what I think is the [originating hadith](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2014/10/07/sufyan-three-from-sabr/):

> Yusuf ibn Absat reported: Sufyan a-Thawri, may Allah have mercy on him, said, “Three qualities are part of patience: not speaking about your sins, nor your pain, nor the purity of your heart.”
>
> Source: Ḥilyat al-Awliyā’ 9397

However I am sure that there are hadith where The Prophet ﷺ has confided in some of his spouses and some of his spouses have confided in him, about various issues including what is translated here as pain. I would be happy to be proven wrong however.

Is it understood that one can talk about your pains/sufferings/hardship to your spouse, while remaining patient, or are they not excluded?

I'm thinking often when my spouse asks how my day has been, I'll share the good and the bad, but I'm wondering if I should be more selective.

Comment: Sufyan a-Thawry is a follower of the followers his words if wisdom can hardly be regarded as hadith nor will there be much commentaries concerning them.

Comment: @Medi1Saif there's always the possibility he was relaying the sentiment of another hadith. Or a hadith that backs up my question.